# Cannot cast from View to ViewFlipper

Tags: java, android, android-view

Hi. I have directly copy and pasted this code but I'm getting casting error: cannot cast from view to viewflipper.

```
public class ViewFlipper extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
{
    Button next;
    Button previous;
    ViewFlipper vf;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        //vf = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);
        next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
        previous = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button02);
        next.setOnClickListener(this);
        previous.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        if (v == next) {
            vf.showNext();
        }
        if (v == previous) {
            vf.showPrevious();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried anything similar but I'd try to checkout if the [ViewFlipper](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ViewFlipper.html) isn't a better way.

Another option would be to have all that as a webpage optimized for mobile view which you load locally with a [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). That way you get full control of how many images to display and how. It is a more flexible solution in my opinion.

Comment: i want to create a layout having backwardand forward buttons.and on this layout,on clicking back/forward buttons different images in drawable folder gets display.How to use intents/any other option so that i dont have to create new .java classes for new images/screens.

Comment: @Maddy: Like I've already mentioned I'd go with a WebView implementation as it gives you a way more flexible approach to what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks Octavian,i have search on the net regarding webview,its all about web based mobile application, while in my application all the resources are local(in drawable),no html, javascript. simple loading of images from drawable on clicking back/next buttons.I have tried your advise to use flipper but i am getting above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
Make sure your class name is not ***ViewFlipper***

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your class name is not ViewFlipper otherwise use like

android.widget.ViewFlipper vf = (android.widget.ViewFlipper)findViewById(R.id.ViewFlipper01);